# ¿Hay alguna manera de ver a que servidores se conecta una app?

Tags: php, webservice, servidor, app

lo que sucede es que necesito optimizar una consulta de datos (de una página y aplicación que no es mía), para realizar los procesos necesito acceder a una página web ingresar sus datos en un formulario en el cual me pide nombre, correo y numero de servicio de mis clientes para yo poder extraer su información. de lo contrario en la aplicación (de la misma empresa) únicamente me pide el número de servicio y ya me proporciona los datos sin necesidad de ingresar nombre y correo; quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de yo poder ver la manera en que se envía los datos la app para yo poder implementarlo en mi propio software.

Comment: Realiza un filtrado de red y mira que transito tiene esa app o página web especifica, cómo, existen varias formas, montando un servidor proxy y desde ahí ver el transito de red, o filtrar la red con herramientas para eso como lo son tpcdump, wireshark, entre otros. Te invito a ver [¿Qué tipo de preguntas evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), ya que estas preguntas basadas en opiniones o demasiado amplias, son cerradas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes utilizar fiddler

https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

con esto puedes ver las llamadas asi como lo parametros enviados, 
si ellos utizan seguridad para conexion tu no podras utilizar sus servicios
de manera abierta.

Saludos